# Looking for CSS to place children of different list items into one line without float on the list item?

Tags: css

I'm working in a legacy environment where it's too challenging to change the HTML rendered to a page. Instead, I'm looking for a CSS solution for a situation where only the child of the list item has an existing class I can use:

HTML structure

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="myobject">A</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject">A</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject">A</div></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><div class="myobject floated">B</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject floated">B</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject floated">B</div></li>
</ul>
```

Desired output

> - A
> - A
> - A
>
> BBB

I've tried

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
li > div {
    display:block;
}
li > div.floated {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

**Updated:**
I found a CSS-only solution that works in my particular case (below)

Comment: realistically I don't think what you want is possible as the display here is based upon the `<li>` tag, not the div tag inside of it. You could use a class on the `li` tags for the second list, but I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: You would need to use scripting for this. You can't style a parent based on child conditions with CSS only.

Comment: Do you have access to `nth-child()` css selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my particular situation using the div to provide the bullet by default, and the extra class to take it away.

```
ul {
    list-style:none; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
li {
    display:inline;
}
li .myobject::before { /* add the new bullet point */
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 0.25em;
    width: 0.25em;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.2em;
}
li .floated {
    display:inline-block;
}
li .floated::before {
    height:0;
    width:0;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: This is a tricky solution, but it looks like it fits the needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Lately in 2017, in the **[Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational)** they have introduced [`:has()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) which will be able to select an element based on its children, **but** it hasn't been approved yet, and [it's not yet supported in any browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility).

**Assumption:**

If it was available it would be very easy by using:

```
li:has(>div.floated) {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

**JS/jQuery:**

But unfortunately, it's not supported yet by any browser, it's however used by jquery or by Javascript `.querySelector()` and you can use it like this:

```
$('li:has(>div.floated)').css({
  "display": "inline-block",
  "float": "left"
});
```

```js
$('li:has(>div.floated)').css({
  "display": "inline-block",
  "float": "left"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="myobject">A</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="myobject">A</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="myobject">A</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="myobject floated">B</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="myobject floated">B</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="myobject floated">B</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Another option:**

Another option is to use another class with the `li` itself instead of its `div`:

```
.myLi {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in my case I'm not able to affect the HTML, nor am I able to insert any extra code to the sites' JS libraries. I did find a CSS-only solution that worked, though.

Comment: @user2033573 You are welcome, but I just wanted to mention all the possible cases and elaborate the situation, and yes I saw your solution it's kind of a tricky solution that can be used. :)

Comment: @user2033573 you could upvote the answer if it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about your legacy environment but You could achieve this by using `nth-child()` selector as shown below. Ofcourse this will only work if you do have access to the mentioned CSS selector.

```css
ul:nth-child(2) {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul:nth-child(2) li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><div class="myobject">A</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject">A</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject">A</div></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><div class="myobject floated">B</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject floated">B</div></li>
    <li><div class="myobject floated">B</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But this has nothing to do with the 'floated' class which is what he's trying to target. This simply targets the 2nd ul in his example.  His production code is not likely going to always be like this.

Comment: True. We don't know the production code but why does it have to do with 'floated' though? The user doesn't seem to specify it. The only thing it says its that his looking for a CSS solution. In which case I think this would work.

Comment: If you re-read the question you’ll see “where only the child of the list item has the class I can use” he’s wanting the li to behave a particular way based on its child divs class. In this case that class is “floated”. Your solution would only ever work on a ul that is the second child of its parent. You’re being too literal with his example.

Comment: Per Wade's response, that particular structure might not exist on all pages. some may have multiple regular lists, some may have both types (in varying number). It was a good suggestion, but I managed to find a different solution that worked for me in any situation!